# How can I get extra GPU working on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, gpu, dual-gpu, cryptomining

I have a small mining rig with 6 GPUs. 1 is a Gigabyte 1070 6GB and the other 5 are MSI 1060 6GBs.

My motherboard is an ASUS Maximus VIII Hero: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/specifications/

This uses the Intel Z170 Chipset: https://ark.intel.com/products/90591/Intel-GL82Z170-PCH

I am currently using PCI-e risers to get all 6 onto the board. I have an extra 1060 that I'm trying to get running on the machine. I purchased this PCI-e 1-to-4 multiplier to split off one of the slots: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1JM6CK2964&Tpk=9SIA1JM6CK2964

I have this plugged into the PCIEX16/X8_1 slot on the board.

The problem I am having is that I am unable to get more than 6 to work at once. Specifically, if I go into Device Manager, one of the 1060s(seems to be "random") will always have a warning on it. When I go into the properties, the message says "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)". If I go into Details, Problem code says 0000002B.

Steps taken:

1. Moved everything around; including swapping out riser cards, changing slots, power supplies to see if any pattern emerges.
2. Reset the CMOS and started over
3. Did a clean install of all the drivers (remove, restart, reinstall)
4. Googled the crap out of this. I see similar problems, but have not found a solution that works.

The card that is left out seems to be arbitrary. It *feels* like this is a game of musical chairs. The first 6 GPUs win and the 7th is left out. Some kind of ceiling I'm hitting.

The multiplier has no manual to be found. The motherboard itself doesn't have an obvious indication that it can't handle it. The chipset claims that it can handle up to 20 PCI-e lanes. I have all onboard devices and ports disabled that are not in use.

Two of the active GPUs(as of right now) are running off of the multiplier card, the one deactivated is one of the motherboard ports that used to work, so it's not a conflict simply on that single multiplied port.

I'm a software guy, not a hardware guy, and I don't expect/want to be spoon fed, but I need someone who knows what the hell they're talking about(unlike me) to give me a nudge in the right direction.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, could you at least be a gentleman and leave a comment as to why?

Comment: Which version do you have of windows? What did it said you the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with a non-obvious registry setting. In case anyone else runs into this.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\xxxx]
"DisplayLessPolicy"=dword:00000001
"LimitVideoPresentSources"=dword:00000001

Replace 'xxxx' with 0001, 0002, etc, for each GPU. The key itself will have a value that shows the name of any given GPU.

An external link for reference: https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=12485